# How to build a sequence using a rolling variable in R

Tags: r, sequence

I'm trying to build a sequence which takes the previous value and adds it to the sequence.

For example:

```
Var1 Var2 
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     A
2     C
2     D
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
1    A   A
1    B   A>B
1    C   A>B>C
2    A   A
2    C   A>C
2    D   A>C>D
```

Is there a package for this? The number of elements in the sequence can get quite large, so my current method using lag within dplyr isn't feasible without writing out the same piece of code n times (where n is the maximum number of elements in a sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you package [runner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/index.html) for sequential functions. Function [runner::runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/reference/runner.html) applies any R function passed to `f` (output `type` needs to be specified)

```
# data
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = rep(c(1,2), each = 3), 
  var2 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2))

# result
library(dplyr)
library(runner)
df %>%
 group_by(var1) %>%
 mutate(var3 = runner(var2, 
                      function(x) paste(x, collapse = ">"),
                      type = "character")) 


 #    var1 var2  var3 
 #   <dbl> <fct> <chr>
 # 1     1 A     A    
 # 2     1 B     A>B  
 # 3     1 C     A>B>C
 # 4     2 A     A    
 # 5     2 B     A>B  
 # 6     2 C     A>B>C
```

Check [documentation](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/index.html) for more options

Answer (score 1):

You could use `by()` and take advantage of the useful R `factor`s. We get `"numeric"`s  by transform/re-transform to factors and back. Generate growing `seq`uences with `Map`, transform to factors again and assign labels according to `Var2`, collapse with `">"`. `c`oncatenate and `unlist` everything and you'll get `"Var3"`. (Might be slow in big data frames, though.)

```
dat$Var3 <- unlist(do.call(c, by(dat, dat$Var1, function(s) {
  r <- Map(seq, as.numeric(factor(s$Var2)))
  r <- lapply(r, levels=1:3, labels=s$Var2, factor)
  return(Map(paste, r, collapse=">"))
})))
dat
#   Var1 Var2  Var3
# 1    1    A     A
# 2    1    B   A>B
# 3    1    C A>B>C
# 4    2    A     A
# 5    2    C   A>C
# 6    2    D A>C>D
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(Var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Var2 = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "C", "D")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
transform(dat, Var3 = ave(Var2, Var1, FUN = function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) paste(x[1:i], collapse = ">"))))

  Var1 Var2  Var3
1    1    A     A
2    1    B   A>B
3    1    C A>B>C
4    2    A     A
5    2    C   A>C
6    2    D A>C>D
```